# continuous-sup property and equicontinuous set.

Tags: real-analysis, equicontinuity

> Suppose that $\Lambda \subset C^{0}$ is equicontinuous and bounded.
>
> (a) Prove that $\sup\{f(x)\mid f \in \Lambda\}$ is a continuous function.
>
> (b) Show that (a) fails without equicontinuity.
>
> (c) Show that this continuous-sup property does not imply equicontinuity.
>
> (d) Assume that the continuous-sup property is true for each subset $\mathcal{F} \subset \Lambda$. Is $\Lambda$ equicontinuous? Give a proof or counterexample.

**My attempt.**

(a) We have that
$$\sup f(x) = \sup (f(x)-f(y) + f(y)) \leq \sup f(y) + \sup(f(x)-f(y)),$$
then
$$\sup f(x) - \sup f(y) \leq \sup (f(x)-f(y)) \leq \Vert f(x) - f(y) \Vert$$
and
$$\sup f(y) - \sup f(x) \leq \sup (f(y)-f(x)) \leq \Vert f(x) - f(y) \Vert,$$
that is,
$$|\sup f(x) - \sup f(y)| \leq \Vert f(x) - f(y) \Vert.$$
Since $\Lambda$ is equicontinuous, given $\epsilon > 0$ there is $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - y| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$ for each $f \in \Lambda$. Therefore,
$$|x - y| < \delta \Longrightarrow |\sup f(x) - \sup f(y)| < \epsilon$$

---

(b) I can see why without equicontinuity, (a) fails: can be exist a function $f$ that not satisfies $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$. But I cannot find a counterexample.

---

(c) Consider $C^{0}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ and $\Lambda = \{f_{n}(x) = x^{n}\}_{n}$. Note that
$$\sup_{x \in [0,1]} f(x) = 1\quad \forall f \in \Lambda.$$
Thus, $g = \sup f$ is continuous, but $\Lambda$ is not equicontinuous.

---

(d) By Mindlack's observation, the same example of (c) works in (d).

---

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$b$: try piecewise affine functions $f_n$ that are $0$ on $[0,1/2n]$ and $1$ on $[1/n,1]$.

$d$: have you tried re-using $c$?

Comment: Of course! Seems to me that (c) works in (d), thank you!

Comment: About (a), what would be the problem?

Comment: Nothing, it works.

Comment: All right. I'll try your suggestion for (b). Thanks!